# Enabling Single Sign on within Teams for botframework virtual assistant

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I created a virtual assistant with the ITSM skill attached with Token Authentication enabled and the bot runs well when using direct line through a browser.

Next, I added it into Teams and after a bit of troubleshooting, I got it working.  I authenticatee and could interact with the VA and the Skill.  The next day however, I was unable to get the bot to prompt for authentication and by then my token authentication had expired.  Next, to verify I have a fix for this issue, I found if I completely cleared my MS Teams cache and my browser directories via the url below, my authentication request prompted this time and I was again able to login and the bot worked correctly.  So my question is, what causes the token in teams to not be able to reprompt, can this be fixed and or is the right way to do authentication in Teams to use a Single Sign On solution and if so how does one do that in Teams with a Virtual Assistant from the botframework?

https://commsverse.blog/2018/09/28/clear-the-microsoft-teams-client-cache/

Comment: Hi. The attachment doesn't seem to work

Comment: Separate to that, where/how are you storing your tokens?

Comment: Try that link sorry

Comment: No exactly sure where it stores the tokens to be honest, I thought it would be in the users store in the cosmos database.

Comment: Now the link just goes somewhere else - something to do with Skype for Business?

Comment: Are you making any effort to try store the token yourself? Perhaps you can send a code sample so we can see better what's currently happening, and also when you're calling for the token. Is it just in a Dialog?

Comment: Finally updated the correct link, I wouldn't know where to store this token. In fact, I am not sure that the cleaning the Teams actually fixed it at this point. I will try it again and see if I can get a token by removing the Teams cached files.

Comment: I am pretty sure the bot stores the token, but with Teams in the mix just not sure how that works.

Comment: Can you attach relevant code samples?

Comment: Do you want the entire Virtual Assistant solution and the ITSM skill solution as well?

Comment: I am seeing the issue, the bot has a value for a token, but the token is expired and I see it go through to the point of calling the API to ServiceNow and the call comes back not authorized.  So it appears that either that teams can't show the actual sign in box, which I have seen it do at least twice or it somehow isn't being told to show the sign-in account box.  Connecting to the same bot via the bot emulator and it works just fine.

Comment: I figured it out, I had to type log out and it logged me out of my session with that token.  After issuing that command, I was able to create a ticket and have me prompt to log back into ServiceNow within MS Teams.  So it appears that the log out feature is used more within Teams than via the web where the token expires and it just prompts on its own to log back in.

Comment: glad you came right